# Cloudfront does not cache the auto-generated sitemap.xml files that are dynamically created by a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, caching, amazon-cloudfront, sitemap

Will Cloudfront cache a dynamic response or will it only cache if it's a physical file on the server? I'm thinking maybe that's why it doesn't cache our sitemap.xml response.

The Cloudfront CDN works fine for our images, css, and js, but not this sitemap.xml request, even with it's own behavior in the Cloudfront distribution.

Stack: Cloudfront, WordPress, Apache, and the sitemap plugin is called XML Sitemap & Google News.

There is no static or physical sitemap.xml file. The plugin generates the response on-the-fly when requested. We want to cache it for 15 mins.

.htaccess looks like this. The cache expires after 900 seconds or 15 minutes.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault                              "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest           "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html                     "access plus 0 seconds"
# Data
ExpiresByType text/xml                      "access plus 15 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/xml               "access plus 15 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/json              "access plus 15 minutes"
# Feed
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml           "access plus 15 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml          "access plus 15 minutes"
```

Cloudfront behavior is set to 600 seconds or 10 mins. I've tried using the headers on the origin as well, no joy.

[image: Cloudfront Behavior]

[image: Request response headers for sitemap.xml]

Comment: Why do you say Cloudfront isn't caching the file? I don't see anything here indicating that. In any case, Cloudfront doesn't know if your resource came from a file or was generated dynamically, so that is definitely not the cause.

Comment: These response headers are missing the header showing a hit/miss from Cloudfront. (x-cache: Hit/Miss from cloudfront), so it's coming from the server directly. For Cloudfront not knowing/caring if the file is dynamic or static, I assumed this, but wasn't sure. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you have other Cloudfront Behaviors that disable caching?

Comment: No, none. There are 3 other behaviors in this order of precedence: *.js, *.css, *sitemap*, and finally Default (*). Default (*) is set to the last precedence and uses the origin cache settings from .htaccess. I also checked .htaccess again for any rules that would take precedence over what I have posted, nothing. I'm going to try caching a different, single, static file and build a custom behavior on CF to cache it and see if it works. I'll report back.

Comment: The origin server seems to be working fine since the `Cache-Control` header matches your htaccess. It looks like this request is simply not hitting Cloudfront at all, which could happen if you were using the origin domain instead of the Cloudfront domain (or alias) in the URL. You can also check logs (on the origin server and Cloudfront) to confirm whether this request is hitting Cloudfront or not.

Comment: Thanks. You are right; the request never hits Cloudfront, because we're not doing full-page caching. I assumed we were and could set behaviors, but we aren't. The resolution will be full-page caching, which will cover the sitemap.